# changing style after jquery declaration

Tags: jquery, sidr

I am using sidr such as

```
 $('#slide-in').sidr({side: 'right',displace: false});
```

after that is initialized I want to

```
  $("#logo").css("display","none");
```

I tried google but I am not sure if "intializing a plug-in" is the right word in this case. 
It would also be helpful to determine if plug-in has been "initiated" already such as

```
if(sidr){
 $("#logo").css("display","none");
}
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by saying after initialized?

Comment: if you place your code after the plugin is called, it should be initialized

Comment: That's what I mean I am not sure if .sidr({}) is initializing the plug-in

Comment: it should initialize the plugin....

Comment: what is your requirement and what is the problem you are facing

Comment: Only once .sider is open I need to hide logo with display:none; But, I feel I need to detect when the menu is open to hide logo if its closed it needs to be there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `onOpen()` method which is a callback that will be executed when your menu is opening:

```
$('#yourMenuId').sidr({
    side: 'right',
    displace: false,
    onOpen: function(name) {
        $("#logo").css("display","none");
    }
});
```

You can find out more option from their docs [**here**](http://www.berriart.com/sidr/#documentation).

Comment: onOpen is one its built in methods?

Comment: Yes, you can find it under documentation section here: http://www.berriart.com/sidr/#documentation

Comment: What if I want to keep the side: 'right',
            displace: false

Comment: Was missing trailing comma. Thanks Felix!